# Python asyncio subprocess code returns "pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception."

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-asyncio

I am trying to convert a synchronous Python process to asyncio.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

This is the synchronous code which successfully starts ffmpeg and converts a directory of webp files into a video.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

output_filename = 'output.mp4'
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -i pipe: -vcodec libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 24 output.mp4'), stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

thepath = '/home/ubuntu/webpfiles/'
thefiles = [f for f in listdir(thepath) if isfile(join(thepath, f))]
for filename in thefiles:
    absolute_path = f'{thepath}{filename}'
    with open(absolute_path, 'rb') as f:
        process.stdin.write(f.read())

process.stdin.close()
process.wait()
process.terminate()
```

This async code fails:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import shlex
import asyncio

outputfilename = 'output.mp4'

async def write_stdin(proc):
    thepath = '/home/ubuntu/webpfiles/'
    thefiles = [f for f in listdir(thepath) if isfile(join(thepath, f))]
    thefiles.sort()
    for filename in thefiles:
        absolute_path = f'{thepath}{filename}'
        with open(absolute_path, 'rb') as f:
            await proc.communicate(input=f.read())

async def create_ffmpeg_subprocess():
    bin = f'/home/ubuntu/bin/ffmpeg'
    params = f'-y -framerate 60 -i pipe: -vcodec libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 24 {outputfilename}'
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        bin,
        *shlex.split(params),
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    return proc

async def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    proc = await create_ffmpeg_subprocess()
    task_stdout = loop.create_task(write_stdin(proc))
    await asyncio.gather(task_stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())
```

The output for the async code is:

```
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
```

etc - one line for each webp file

Comment: This usually means there is an issue with network communications between your miner and the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

Instead of :

```
    await proc.communicate(input=f.read())
```

The correct way to write to stdin in:

```
    proc.stdin.write(f.read())
    await proc.stdin.drain()
```

Complete example:

```
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import shlex
import asyncio

outputfilename = 'output.mp4'

async def read_stdout(proc):
    while True:
        line = await proc.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            line = line.decode()
            print(line, end='')

async def read_stderr(proc):
    while True:
        line = await proc.stderr.readline()
        if line:
            line = line.decode()
            print(line, end='')
            if "Output" in line:
                if outputfilename in line:
                    print('finished!!!!')

async def write_stdin(proc):
    thepath = '/home/ubuntu/webpfiles/'
    thefiles = [f for f in listdir(thepath) if isfile(join(thepath, f))]
    thefiles.sort()
    for filename in thefiles:
        absolute_path = f'{thepath}{filename}'
        print('.', end='')
        with open(absolute_path, 'rb') as f:
            proc.stdin.write(f.read())
            await proc.stdin.drain()

async def create_ffmpeg_subprocess():
    bin = f'/home/ubuntu/bin/ffmpeg'
    params = f'-y -threads 1 -framerate 60 -thread_queue_size 4096 -i pipe: -vcodec libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:-1 -r 10 {outputfilename}'
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        bin,
        *shlex.split(params),
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    return proc

async def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    proc = await create_ffmpeg_subprocess()
    task_stderr = loop.create_task(read_stderr(proc))
    task_stdout = loop.create_task(read_stdout(proc))
    task_stdin = loop.create_task(write_stdin(proc))
    await asyncio.gather(task_stderr, task_stdin, task_stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Comment: I planned to answer that `proc.communicate` terminates the sub-process, and we may replace it with `proc.stdin.write(f.read())`.  I am not sure if we have to call `await proc.stdin.drain()` multiple times. For closing `stdin` pipe, I added `await proc.communicate(b'')` at the bottom of `write_stdin(proc)` method. It seems to work.

Comment: @rotem the docs say we should write then await drain https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=streamwriter#asyncio.StreamWriter.drain